# Script for counting and summarising Numbers & Unique numbers in each line

Tags: linux, shell-script, centos, awk, sort

```
timestamp : IDs returned
20160420084726:-
20160420085418:[111783178, 111557953, 111646835, 111413356, 111412662, 105618372, 111413557]
20160420085418:[111413432, 111633904, 111783198, 111792767, 111557948, 111413225, 111413281]
20160420085418:[111413432, 111633904, 111783198, 111792767, 111557948, 111413225, 111413281]
20160420085522:[111344871, 111394583, 111295547, 111379566, 111352520]
20160420090022:[111344871, 111394583, 111295547, 111379566, 111352520]
```

timestamp is in the format YYYYMMDDhhmmss

·       ads is a comma separated list of ad asset IDs surrounded by square brackets, or - if no ads were returned

I need to write a script that outputs, for each ten minute slice of the day:

1. The count of IDs that were returned
2. The count of unique IDs that were returned
3. The script should support a command line parameter to select whether unique or total IDs should be given.

Example output using the above log excerpt (in total mode):

```
20160420084:0
20160420085:26
20160420090:5
```

And in unique count mode it would give:

```
20160420084:0
20160420085:19
20160420090:5
```

This is were I am so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
awk -F":" ' { print $1":" $2 } ' file.log | sort -r | uniq -c
```

Results:

```
1 20160420090022:[111344871, 111394583, 111295547, 111379566, 111352520] 
1 20160420085522:[111344871, 111394583, 111295547, 111379566, 111352520] 
1 20160420085418:[111783178, 111557953, 111646835, 111413356, 111412662, 105618372, 111413557] 
2 20160420085418:[111413432, 111633904, 111783198, 111792767, 111557948, 111413225, 111413281] 
1 20160420084726:- 
7: –
```

Comment: Please read through [the editing help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and apply proper formatting to your post - otherwise it is quite hard to decipher. Please also note that this is not a scripting service. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? I suggest using `awk` as the weapon of choice here.

Comment: "_I need to write a script"_ - excellent. Please show us what you've got so far. Describe what happens when you run it and what you expected to happen. Include any errors you've got. Paste it into https://shellcheck.net and address any errors it reports with your script. How have you attempted to resolve any outstanding issues?

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for arrays of arrays (and `length(array)` but most awks have that these days):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=":" }
NR>1 {
    time = substr($1,1,11)
    totIds[time] += 0
    if ( gsub(/[][ ]/,"",$2) ) {
        totIds[time] += split($2,ids,/,/)
        for ( i in ids ) {
            unqIds[time][ids[i]]
        }
    }
}
END {
    for ( time in totIds ) {
        print time, ( type ~ /^tot/ ? totIds[time] : length(unqIds[time]) )
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -v type='tot' -f tst.awk file
20160420084:0
20160420085:26
20160420090:5
```

```
$ awk -v type='unq' -f tst.awk file
20160420084:0
20160420085:19
20160420090:5
```

If you don't have GNU awk you can do this same with any awk with just slightly more code and memory usage:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=":" }
NR>1 {
    time = substr($1,1,11)
    totIds[time] += 0
    if ( gsub(/[][ ]/,"",$2) ) {
        totIds[time] += split($2,ids,/,/)
        for ( i in ids ) {
            if ( !seen[time,ids[i]]++ ) {
                numUnq[time]++
            }
        }
    }
}
END {
    for ( time in totIds ) {
        print time, ( type ~ /^tot/ ? totIds[time] : numUnq[time]+0 )
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -v type='tot' -f tst.awk file
20160420084:0
20160420085:26
20160420090:5
```

```
$ awk -v type='unq' -f tst.awk file
20160420084:0
20160420085:19
20160420090:5
```

Answer (score 0):

```perl
$ cat summarise.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use List::Util qw(sum0); # useful function to sum elements of array

# handle command-line options
use Getopt::Long qw(VersionMessage :config gnu_getopt);
use Pod::Usage;
$main::VERSION='0.0-alpha';
my $help = 0;
my $type;
GetOptions('total|sum|s|t' => sub { $type .=  't' },
           'unique|u'      => sub { $type .=  'u' },
           'both|b'        => sub { $type  = 'tu' },
           'help|h|?'      => \$help,
           'version|V'     => sub { VersionMessage() },
          ) or pod2usage(2);
pod2usage(-exitval => 0, -verbose => 2) if $help or (! @ARGV && -t);
$type = 'b' if length($type) > 1;
$type = 'u' if length($type) == 0; # default is unique

# Hash-of-Hashes (HoH) to hold timestamps, ids, and id counts.
# Primary key will be timestamp, secondary keys are the IDs,
# and values are the counts of each secondary key.
my %timestamps;

# read and process input file
while(<<>>) {
  next if ($. == 1); # skip first line of input file(s)
  chomp;

  # remove square brackets and spaces from input line
  s/[][]|\s+//g;

  # split current line on colon and commas
  my($ts,@ids) = split /[:,]/;
  $ts = substr($ts,0,11);
  $timestamps{$ts} = () unless (defined $timestamps{$ts});

  # remove non-numeric elements of @ids array
  @ids = grep { /^\d+$/ } @ids;

  # Convert to the HoH structure.
  map { $timestamps{$ts}{$_}++ } @ids;

  close(ARGV) if eof; # reset line counter $. at end of each input file
}

# all input has been processed, so print the results.
foreach my $ts (sort keys %timestamps) {
  my $u = scalar keys %{ $timestamps{$ts} };
  my $s = sum0 values %{ $timestamps{$ts} };

  if ($type eq 'u') {
    printf "%s: %i\n", $ts, $u;
  } elsif ($type eq 't') {
    printf "%s: %i\n", $ts, $s;
  } elsif ($type eq 'b') {
    printf "%s: %i, %i\n", $ts, $u, $s;
  };
}

__END__

=head1 summarise.pl

Script for counting and summarising Numbers & Unique numbers in each line.

=head1 SYNOPSIS

summarise.pl [options] [file ...]

=head1 OPTIONS

=over

=item B<--total>

print total number of IDs per timestamp

=item B<--unique>

print number of unique IDs per timestamp

=item B<--both>

print both unique and total number of IDs

=item B<--version>

Print script's version and exit

=item B<--help>

Print this help message and exit

=back
=cut
```

Note: [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util), [Pod::Usage](https://perldoc.perl.org/Pod::Usage), and [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Long) are all core perl modules and are included with perl.

See `perldoc pod` for details on how perl's "Plain Old Documentation" built-in code documentation works. I've barely even scratched the surface of what this can do.

Sample output:

```
$ ./summarise.pl input.txt 
20160420084: 0
20160420085: 19
20160420090: 5

$ ./summarise.pl input.txt -t
20160420084: 0
20160420085: 26
20160420090: 5

$ ./summarise.pl input.txt -b
20160420084: 0, 0
20160420085: 19, 26
20160420090: 5, 5

$ ./summarise.pl  --version
./summarise.pl version 0.0-alpha
(Getopt::Long::GetOptions version 2.51; Perl version 5.32.1)

$ ./summarise.pl  --help
summarise.pl
    Script for counting and summarising Numbers & Unique numbers in each
    line.

SYNOPSIS
    summarise.pl [options] [file ...]

OPTIONS
    --total, --sum, -t, -s
        print total number of IDs per timestamp

    --unique, -u
        print number of unique IDs per timestamp

    --both, -b
        print both unique and total number of IDs

    --version, -V
        Print script's version and exit

    --help, -h, -?
        Print this help message and exit
```

BTW, like the GNU `getopt_long()` function used by many C programs, the perl `Getopt::Long` module understands abbreviations for option - e.g. `--uni`, `--uniq`, `-un`, etc will be treated the same as `-u` or `--unique`.   As long as the abbreviation is long enough to unambiguously correspond to an option name, it will work.

---

And, in case you're wondering what the `%timestamps` Hash-of-Hashes data structure "looks like":

```perl
{
  "20160420084" => undef,
  "20160420085" => { 
     105618372 => 1, 111295547 => 1, 111344871 => 1, 111352520 => 1, 111379566 => 1,
     111394583 => 1, 111412662 => 1, 111413225 => 2, 111413281 => 2, 111413356 => 1,
     111413432 => 2, 111413557 => 1, 111557948 => 2, 111557953 => 1, 111633904 => 2,
     111646835 => 1, 111783178 => 1, 111783198 => 2, 111792767 => 2,
  },
  "20160420090" => {
     111295547 => 1, 111344871 => 1, 111352520 => 1, 111379566 => 1, 111394583 => 1
  },
}
```

A Hash-of-Hashes is an associative array ("hash") where every element can also be a hash.

See `perldoc perldsc` for details on perl data structures.